# Java - MVC - Right click on Jbutton

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm stucked trying to use MVC with Jbuttons and check if was pressed with left or right mouse click.

When I has to deal with a single(left) click the approach what I use is the following:

```
MyView extends JFrame{

    JButton[] mybuttons;

    public MyView(){
        //init mybuttons with a proper setActionCommand("button_name")
    }

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        for(JButton button:mybuttons){
            button.addActionListener(al);
        }
    }
}

MyController {
    MyModel mymodel;
    MyView myview;

    public MyController(MyModel mymodel,MyView myview){
        this.mymodel=mymodel;
        this.myview=myview;
        this.myview.setActionListener(new MyControllerActionListener());
    }

    public class MyControllerActionListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            String command = ae.getActionCommand();
            switch (command){
                case "Button0":
                    ...
                    break;
                case "Button1":
                    ...
                    break;
        }
}
```

Now I want to use the same approach with MouseAdapter, so I've tried:

```
public class MyMouseControllerAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
           System.out.println("Left click");
        }
        else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            System.out.println("Right click");
        }

    }
}
```

But I don't find a way to **check what jbutton was pressed**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get the source of the `MouseEvent`, and see which component it is :

```
JButton source = (JButton )e.getSource();

if(source == mybuttons[0]){
  // do stuff
}
else if(source == mybuttons[1]){
  // do stuff
}
...
```